# Sequential function calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an array of asynchronous functions, it is necessary to call in order and the result of the call of the previous function is passed into the arguments. How can this be done approximately?

Comment: Tried [promsie chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)?

Comment: Tried async waterfall https://www.codementor.io/@aminmeyghani/running-asynchronous-javascript-code-in-sequence-with-async-waterfall---part-1-du1084fmx ?

Comment: @NullDev @Sascha   eg                                                                                   
 `const firstPromise = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(300)), 300);

const secondPromise = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(200)), 200);

const thirdPromise = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(100)), 100);

promisesInSeries([firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise]); Execute resolve (300) after 300 ms, then resolve (200) after 200 ms, then resolve (100) after 100 ms`

Answer (score 1):

```
// lets say we have a function that takes a value and adds 20 to it asynchronously
const asyncPlus20 = num => Promise.resolve(num+a)
const arr = [asyncPlus20, asyncPlus20]

let res = 0 // some starting value
for (const f of arr) res = await f(res)
// res is now 20
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way for **Array of Async functions** is to use **For...of**.

*Run the below snippet in the console.* >> Also includes the argument passing

```
const twoSecondsPromise = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('2000_'), 2000);
    })
};

const threeSecondsPromise = (val) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(val + '3000_'), 3000);
    })
};

const fiveSecondsPromise = (val) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(val + '5000_'), 5000);
    })
};

(async function () {
    const asyncFunctions = [twoSecondsPromise, threeSecondsPromise, fiveSecondsPromise];
    let result;
    for (const file of asyncFunctions) {
        result = await file(result);
        console.log(result);
     }
})();
```

Comment: What makes you think this is the best way? Using `reduce` with promises creates a lot overhead compared to a simple loop with `await`.

Comment: Bergi, sorry but can you please explain me what you mean by overhead. I thought reduce was similar to the for--of loop. how are those 2 different

Comment: The `reduce` is immediately iterating the whole array and building `N` promises that will have to be resolved one after the other. The `for` loop with an `await`ing body does not, it is more efficient and flexible.

Comment: (I would have understood if you had used `return asyncFunctions.reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve(undefined))` which at least is elegant, but the outer-scope `result` and complicated `async`/`await` just have too much overhead - especially syntactical).